# issue with xml parsing data to sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I am working on SQL query where i need to parse xml to sql .Query is working for other xml but not working for below xml. query i am using is as below

```
DECLARE @xmldata XML 
SET @xmldata =
N'<SearchProductsResponse xmlns="http://api.abc.com/">
<productItems>
<productItem id="5d0ee86d84bcc5edef43236d61419a59">
<trackingLinks>
<trackingLink adspaceId="100">
<ppv>
 abc.com
</ppv>
<ppc>
abc.com
</ppc>
</trackingLink>
</trackingLinks>
</productItem>
</productItems>
</SearchProductsResponse>';

select
    t1.c.value('@id', 'varchar(300)') as itemid,
    c.c.value('@id', 'int') as adspaceId
from 
    @xmldata.nodes('*:SearchProductsResponse/*:productItems/*:productItem') as t1(c)
    OUTER APPLY t1.c.nodes('*:trackingLinks/*:trackingLink') as c(c)
```

Output I am getting is

```
itemid                            adspaceId
5d0ee86d84bcc5edef43236d61419a59    NULL
```

But I should return `100 instead of NULL` . This query is working for other XML but don't know whats wrong with this XML. I have double check XML and query  nothing different from other XML. Hope I am not missing some silly mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the attribute selection for your adspaceId column to `@adspaceId`.

```
select
t1.c.value('@id', 'varchar(300)') as itemid,
c.c.value('@adspaceId', 'int') as adspaceId
from @xmldata.nodes('*:SearchProductsResponse/*:productItems/*:productItem') as t1(c)
OUTER APPLY t1.c.nodes('*:trackingLinks/*:trackingLink') as c(c)
```

Comment: Oh.. I knew that its silly mistake from my side.. Thanks for your help